# Possible combinations of -1 0 & +1

Tags: r

Surveys offered to customers to provide feedback on the consultant that they dealt with. Customer    gives a score of 1 to 10.

```
Scores are grouped as:
1-6
7-8
9-10
If score <= 6 then this = detractor which constitutes a negative one: -1
7-8 = 0 (neutral)
Scores of 9 and 10 = +1.
```

So although there are 10 possible responses by the customer (1:10) this ends up being either -1, 0     or +1. So only 3 possible outcomes: -1,0,+1.

Say 10 surveys are done it may looks like this:

```
-1,+1,0,0,+1,+1,-1,+1,0,0 = +2
```

Then this +2 is divided by survey counts and multiplied by 100. So 2/10 = 0.2 * 
    100 = 20.

```
Now to the tricky part.
```

I want to figure out the possible sum totals (like the +2 calc'd 5 lines up). Best explained with a     simple example:

```
1 Survey = either a -1, 0 or +1 so 3 possible outcomes.
2 surveys possibilities

-1,-1 equals -2
-1,0 equals -1
-1,+1 equals 0
0,0 equals 0
0,1 equals +1
+1,+1 equals 2
```

So although there are 6 possible combinations this is not what I am after. The order and individual     totals are not what I am after it's just the possible sum of n surveys. In this case there's only one -2, -1, +1 and +2. That's 4. But there are 2 combinations that sum to zero so this is only 1 possible outcome from a sum perspective. So in this case given 2 surveys there is only 5 possible summed amounts.

I can do these simple one's by hand but what if there were 20 surveys? That'd be silly obviously. I would like to know if there is a way that in R I can use an algorithm to solve this for as many surveys that I need to examine this for.

Comment: How is `-1,+1 equals 0` different from `0,0 equals 0`, but e.g. `-1,0 equals -1` same as `0,-1 equals -1`?

Comment: Obviously, the sum can range from `-n` to `+n` where `n` is the number of surveys, a total of `2 n + 1` possible sums.

Comment: If there are 20 surveys, the sum is between `-20` and `+20`, making `41` possible sums. In general, for `n` surveys, there will be `2n+1` possible sums.

Comment: This isn't exactly about programming. I guess http://math.stackexchange.com/ would be a better fit.

Answer (score 2):

As written in the comments above:
*Obviously, the sum can range from -n to +n where n is the number of surveys, a total of 2 n + 1 possible sums. –  Gassa 11 mins ago*

This is a way you can reach this conclusion:

Start to create the full logic table of the outcome

```
  +1 +1   2
  +1  0   1
  +1 -1   0
   0 +1   1
   0  0   0
   0 -1  -1
  -1 +1   0
  -1  0  -1
  -1 -1  -2
```

So with 2 surveys you have to 2^3 possible outcomes, with a few duplicates boiling down to the unique set 2,1,0,-1,-2

combine this with the next survey

```
+1  +2  3
+1  +1  2
+1   0  1
 [..]

-1  0   -1
-1 -1   -2
-1 -2   -3
```

For every new survey you add you will end up with

```
+1  +(N-1)   N
+1  +(N-2)   N-1
    [..]

-1 -(N-2)   -(N-1)
-1 -(N-1)   -N
```

The conclusion would be the max and min outcome will be +-N where N is the number of surveys given.

Maybe this article on wikipedia about 3-way logic is what you are looking for:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic